# Does $\Bbb{K}[\![z,z^{-1}]\!]=\Bbb{K}(\!(z)\!)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, commutative-algebra, terminology

In terms of formal series we can define the formal power series $\Bbb{K}[\![z,z^{-1}]\!]$ as any series that takes the form:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$$
whilst the formal Laurent series $\Bbb{K}(\!(z)\!)$ is defined as any sequence that takes the form:
$$\sum_{n=d}^\infty a_nz^n$$
clearly $\Bbb{K}(z)\subset \Bbb{K}[\![z,z^{-1}]\!]$ but does the definition of a formal Laurent series usually permit $d=-\infty$? in which case we would have $\Bbb{K}(z)= \Bbb{K}[\![z,z^{-1}]\!]$.

Comment: No, it does not permit $d = -\infty$. Alternatively, one may say that formal Laurent series are of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$, with only finitely many $a_n\neq 0$ for negative indices (that's how [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_Laurent_series) formulates it).

Comment: According to this link : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series?wprov=sfla1  , the $a_n$'s have to be $0$ for all but finitely many negative indices

Comment: You mean $K((z)) = K[[z]] \ [z^{-1}]$

Comment: Note in $K[[z]] \ [[z^{-1}]]$ you can write $(1-z)^{-1}$ in two ways : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z_n$ and $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{-n}$ ie.  $(1-z)\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^{n} = 0$.
So those are zero divisors and $K[[z]] \ [[z^{-1}]]$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: @reuns: that second expression does not make sense in $K[[z]][z^{-1}]$, which is just the field of Laurent series. If you meant to talk about $K[[z, z^{-1}]$, which is strictly larger, this is worse than not being an integral domain, it is not even a ring at all.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe I don't follow you. $K[[z]]$ is an integral domain whose unique maximal ideal (of non-inversible elements) is $(z)$ thus $K[[z]] \ [z^{-1}] = K((z))$ is its fraction field (it is also the completion of $K(z)\ $). Yes I should have noted $K[[z]] [[z^{-1}]]$ (supposed to be a "completion" of $K[[z]] \, [z^{-1}] \ $ or of $K[z,z^{-1}]$) is not even a ring.

Comment: Beside that, the OP's confusion probably comes from complex analysis, where we consider the ring of analytic functions $f(z)$ on $r < |z| < R$ which is also the ring of Laurent series $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$ converging absolutely on $r < | z| < R$.

Comment: @reuns: sorry, looks like I misread $K[[z]][[z^{-1}]]$ as $K[[z]][z^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 9):

$K[[z, z^{-1}]]$ is not even a *ring*, let alone a field, let alone the field of fractions of anything: if you try to write down the product of two arbitrary series you'll find that you need to define arbitrary infinite sums of elements in $K$. At best it is a module over Laurent polynomials $K[z, z^{-1}]$.

As a module over Laurent polynomials $K[[z, z^{-1}]]$ has some curious elements in it. For example, the element $\delta(z - 1) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} z^n$ has the curious feature that $z^n \delta(z - 1) = \delta(z - 1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and consequently for any Laurent polynomial $f(z)$ we have

$$f(z) \delta(z - 1) = f(1) \delta(z - 1).$$

Similarly $K[[z, z^{-1}]]$ contains elements that deserve to be called $\delta(z - c)$ for $c \in K^{\times}$.

Comment: My answer is different from yours. Is it false? Are there more that one possible interpretation of the question? If you have enough time to look at my answer, I'd be happy to have your opinion about it.

Answer (score 0):

$K((z))$, the field of fractions of $K[[z]]$ is the  field of (formal) Laurent series, since the latter is the smallest field which contains $K[[z]]$.